# How would you say "es muy psicólogo"?

Tags: expressions, translation

Good afternoon!
In Spanish, some people tend to say: "fulanito es muy psicólogo". How would you say  in English that a person is "muy psicólogo o psicóloga"?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: People vary greatly in how they want to talk about their mental health, so there’s no general answer. There are as many expressions for receiving psychotherapy as there are for being drunk.

Comment: What does it mean in English? (Even if the translation doesn't sound right.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I think I didn't explain it properly... I do apologize! My question is not related to people receiving psychoterapy. I would like to know if I can use an equivalent expression (in English) to the Spanish one: "Fulanito es muy psicólogo". For instance, I wonder whether the expression "So-and-so is a great deal psychologist" exists in English...

Comment: Please see our [help on translation questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info). Note that you have to assume the community doesn't know anything about your Spanish phrase.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey There is nothing wrong with providing an English-equivalent phrase. We just need to know what's trying to be expressed.

Comment: What's the closest meaning to *great deal* that you can think of? *Person is a (good / great / competent / skilled) psychologist*? Is it an idiom in Spanish, or just a simple sentence?

Comment: @Cristina does your phrase mean the person actually *is* a psychologist, or isn't one but knows a lot about it?

Comment: “He’s a **real** psychologist,” is parallel and seems to cover a similar meaning (although, depending on context, it can also mean the mere fact that someone is an accredited psychologist). I’m not familiar enough with the idiom in Spanish to say if that’s the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think the expression *"fulanito es muy psicólogo"* in Spanish sounds quite right.

However, at least one Doctor has written on the usage of the phrase...

> [image]

[José Carlos Fuertes Rocañín,  (Iberia)  *"¿Qué me pasa, doctor?"*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RMY90-e5ZcUC&pg=PT137&lpg=PT137&dq=%22es%20muy%20psic%C3%B3logo%22&source=bl&ots=TuQDdYAUUW&sig=ACfU3U3jlUSCmT4JRX9D3nnzAjzXpXUJrg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS1KXBm9_hAhULU1AKHTYfDr4Q6AEwBHoECDAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22es%20muy%20psic%C3%B3logo%22&f=false)

"Possibly no person comes to know themselves completely, but it is evident that some people know themselves better than others do. This is because some individuals have an innate ability of introspection, reflection, and self-analysis. Generally they are also understanding of others and are gifted with an unusual perspicacity in understanding the secrets of others. Informally it is said of that person that he/she "*es muy psicólogo , o tiene mucha psicología*... ("he *is very psychologist*, or they *have a lot of psychology*")

(Thanks to Michael Harvey for the link.)

To me it sounds like something Marilyn Monroe might say in one of her dim blonde roles...

> "That guy is ***very pschological***"

I think that would convey the slangy street language aspect of the original phrase.

On the other hand, it would be more formal to say that the person is

- ***perspicacious, or  insightful***

Answer (score 3):

I am a speaker of Spanish and would tend to interpret the sentence in question as being equivalent to:

- He is **a good deal of** a psychologist.

(meaning that the person is not a psychologist proper, but embodies many of the features psychologists are typically endowed with)

If OP's intention is to emphasize the quality of the psychologist, then any of the options suggested by @Jason Bassford will work (*good, great, competent, skilled*). Another adjective that comes to mind is "archetypical", in which case the definite article will be used:

- He/She is the archetypical psychologist.

"Es muy psicólogo" could be used in the latter sense to mean something like:

- He's not just a psychologist. He's the perfect one.

Comment: Gustavson, and Cristina: I found this secondary meaning of psicólogo/psicóloga: "Persona capacitada de modo especial para el conocimiento del carácter y la forma de pensar de las personas." I would feel a difference might be that a psychologist in the literal sense is trained (and may have some natural inborn ability) whereas this meaning concentrates on the natural ability.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In that case, "a good deal of a psychologist" will convey the intended meaning.

Comment: But _es muy psicólogo"_ doesn't sound like very good Spanish. Do they use that kind of expression in your part of the world? We would say something like _"es buen psicólogo"_ ...

Comment: Cascabel, José Carlos Fuertes Rocañín, a psychiatrist in Zaragoza, Spain (Iberia) has written a book, "¿Qué me pasa, doctor?" in which he says that people having a perspicacity in understanding other people's secrets are informally said to be 'muy psicologico' - "Vulgarmente se dice de alguien así que «es **muy psicólogo**» o que «tiene mucha psicología»."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I notice he said _vulgarmente_....that sounds about right. It is not something an educated person would say. Do you mind if I steal that source for my answer?...or are you going to post your own?

Comment: Surely _vulgarmente_ just means 'ordinarily, popularly', does it necessarily mean the user is 'uneducated'? My main second language is French, and 'vulgairement' has two meanings, one neutral : "De façon courante, ordinaire", and one pejorative : "Avec vulgarité, sans distinction, d'une manière grossière" (Larousse).

Comment: @Cascabel (off-topic comment) so is the Spanish version 'poor' grammar, using an adverb to modify a noun? As though they're saying 'very psychologist'?

Comment: Yup...and it ain't just me. Everyone in my house thinks it sounds "off" @Mitch

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, maybe "informal" would work better. But in our house it sounds kinda uneducated..

Comment: Pressing nouns into service as adjectives is very common in many languages. I do not like to hear the language of ordinary people called 'uneducated' which is why I have been pursuing this point.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "popularly" and "ordinarily" it isn't. I have never heard the usage until I read this Q. I am updating my answer and will use different language.

Comment: @Mitch On the other hand, it is very common in Mexico to say of a macho man.. _"el es muy hombre"_

Comment: @Mitch What's happening here is that in colloquial Spanish you are idiomatically allowed to use the adverb/intensifier *muy* with a substantive (i.e., a noun—and in practice usually a profession) in a copula’s complement as an expression that roughly means "is quite the X" or "isn't much of an X". Like you could apologize for serving a guest a not very fancy meal by saying [*Es que no soy muy cocinero/a*](http://www.wordreference.com/esfr/cocinero) — that is, I'm not much of a cook, or with *Fulanito es muy cocinero* to say (possibly ironically) that so-and-so's quite the chef. ¿Understand?

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, this is an idiomatic construction in Spanish, and not at all an uncommon one either, at least as casually spoken in Spain. I haven't noticed its absence in non-Iberian dialects, but I haven’t looked for it, either. It has a casual ring to it, like adding *el* or *la* before a person’s name does: *Aquí viene la María* for here comes “that” Maria. You hear it in dialogue all the time, and it’s no more (or less) considered “bad grammar” than using the definite article with a person's name is. You wouldn’t use it in a formal essay, but it’s quite normal in friendly/sarcastic speech.

Comment: @tchrist Nevertheless, here we would not use that expression _muy psicologo_...it sounds off. The usage is for somebody who is not actually a psychologist by profesion, but someone who is insightful.

Comment: @Cascabel I hope that this helps you perceive the “register” (formality) this construction gets used in. Its casual nature makes it difficult to look up in dictionaries like the [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QAgVTQ3), which doesn't even mention this usage. I’m still hunting up formal explanations in published reference works or academic papers. It would make a good original question to pose on [spanish.se].

Comment: @tchrist Your example of _muy cocinero_ was a good one, and in common use..  However, with this usage...of _muy psicologo_...I don't know. I understand the register, as I explained to Michael. It just sounds uneducated. In 3rd world countries like mine, roughly 40% of the people never make it past 4th grade.

Comment: @Cascabel Do you mean about migrating this particular, or working to get this one reopened once the asker returns to be a bit more explicit for the non-Spanish-speakers here, or about asking a new question over there about the entire *ser muy «sustantivo»* construction itself?

Comment: I wrote that comment about 10 minutes before the Q closed. So now I am thinking get the new Q about the usage of  "_ser muy «sustantivo»_  construction"posted on Spanish.SE, and then incorporate _that_ information back into _this_ Q. Then move to re-open. That said, I don't think there is actually gonna be a "perfect" answer in this case. @tchrist

Comment: @Cascabel That sounds like a good plan. Why don't you go ahead and pose the new question sobre esta curiosa construcción "ser muy «sustantivo»” over there on [spanish.se] yourself, if you could please be so kind? I shall continue my fight with the Google monster, but this may require me to page through various printed monolingual Spanish books I have buried somewhere down in my basement that cover colloquial Spanish better than I seem to be able to Google up easily.

Comment: @tchrist Take a look. [Gustavson beat me to it.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/29211/c%c3%b3mo-interpretan-es-muy-psic%c3%b3logo)  This Sunday was very busy for us. Apart from the Easter celebration, we were also celebrating 2 birthdays. And on Monday when I woke up, the family was still here!

Comment: Glad to find a thread about this topic, it appeared in a spanish book I'm reading. tchrist's "is quite the X" sounds pretty good.  If in a sarcastic tone, maybe "although he's such a great X..."

Answer (score 1):

I would say an idiomatic equivalent is

> He's a bit of a psychologist.

The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_bit_of_a_%25E2%2580%2594) has the phrase:

> **a bit of a —**
> PHRASE
>
> **1** Used to suggest that something is not severe or extreme, or is the case only to a limited extent.
>
> *he's a bit of a womanizer*

However I think the dictionary definition is a bit weak, as the phrase can be used as under-statement. In my example, the meaning is that he isn't actually a psychologist, but he knows a lot about it.

Comment: I would have mixed feelings about being called 'a bit of a psychologist'. We have all met those annoying types who know (or think they know) everybody's innermost secrets and motivations better than they do themselves. Also, a snake-oil salesman or a con artist is often a bit of a psychologist.

Comment: Using "a bit of a" does capture that it's saying "something of a" in front of the noun, but *muy* is stronger than just a little.

Comment: @tchrist we Brits rather like understatement.